# Conversión de números con recursión en (C)

Tags: c, recursión

Buen día gente, hice un programa que convierte un número decimal ya sea a binario, octal o hexadecimal, pero necesito que mi función `convertir` sea recursiva.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>

void convertir(int num, int base);

main()
{
    int opc=0,num=0,base=0;

    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("1.Binario\n");
        printf("2.Octal\n");
        printf("3.Hexa\n");
        printf("4.Salir\n");
        printf("Opcion: ");
        scanf("%d",&opc);
        printf("Numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1:convertir(num,2); break;//las operaciones dentro de la función se harán con 2
            case 2:convertir(num,8);break; //las operaciones dentro de la función se harán con 8
            case 3:convertir(num,16);break; //las operaciones dentro de la función se harán con 16
            case 4:break;
            default: printf("No valido\n"); break;

        }
        getch();        
    }while(opc!=4);
}

void convertir(int num, int base)
{
    int res=0,coc=0;
    printf("        ");
        do{
            res=num%base;
            coc=num/base;
            if(coc!=0) return 0;
            if(res<10)printf("\b\b%d",res);
            else printf("\b\b%c",res+55);   //para imprimir las letras si es en base hexadecimal    
            num=coc;    
        }while(coc!=0);

}
```

Mi problema es que no sé como aplicar la recursión, en esta ocasión sé que necesito poner un caso base, pero una de mis dudas es sobre eso.

En mi función `convertir`el ciclo se repite siempre y cuando `coc`es diferente de 0, no sé si esto será mi caso base o deba ser otra instrucción.

Además no me convierte el número a la base que yo le indique.

Sinceramente estoy perdida en cuanto a eso, estoy tratando de mejorar mi lógica al programar y quiero entender cuales son mis errores.

Espero me puedan dar algunos consejos que me puedan ayudar, se los agradecería bastante, si hay algunos errores de redacción, disculpen, es mi primera pregunta aquí.

Answer (score 1):

> Mi problema es que no sé como aplicar la recursión.

[Recursión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n) es cuando una función se llama a si misma. Así que ya sabes cómo aplicarlo.

> Sé que necesito poner un caso base, […] En mi función `convertir` el ciclo se repite siempre y cuando `coc` es diferente de 0, no sé si esto será mi caso base o deba ser otra instrucción.

El caso base de recursión es el que rompe la recursión, es necesario tenerlo o de lo contrario la recursión no acabaría nunca. Examinar el cociente es, efectivamente, la manera de romper la recursión.

---

La estrategia recursiva sería obtener el dígito, dividir el número y volver a llamar a la función con el número ya dividido:

```
void convertir(int num, int base)
{
    if (num) // Caso base: Debe haber número que convertir
    {
        // Obtener residuo.
        int res = num % base;
        // Llamada recursiva.
        convertir(num / base, base);
        // Imprimir.
        printf("%c", (res > 9 ? 'A' + (res - 10) : '0' + res)); 
    }
}
```

Imprimimos **después** de la recursión para que el número no se imprima en orden inverso. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7LDoIwEEXXzFfcaAxtrAoLSRAf8VOwVG0CxRRwY/h27ODC3cyZ@xi90XXpHtO0tE7XQ2Vw7PrKttvnmejd2gq6dW/je@uFdT3c0CjwcCs7I@lDkb1DBCopCkvEJ286nFiJ1SwrAv@nMN/NXP1C@PzywXgXi5VeKAgOOCPHBfE1xvoHNkgTiQPihFEgkp0jjURc2pTWCX54fupft0/zLFNIM1Z70w/eISlonKYv)</kbd>.